# Google Drive Auth2: How to fix Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: c#, drive

I am trying to perform and auth2 request for google drive and am getting a redirecturi mismatch error.
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecret etc..

```
   how do we set the redirecturi property to have the same redirect uris has defined when setting up the app?
   It was mentioned the fix for Google Drive v2 but I am using v3 and these are not working.
   I do not see a way, in the code, to set the google drive auth redirect uri.         
   There must be away.
```

Code is the following:

```
        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,};
        var clientId = "txdjxtd.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        var clientSecret = "didididijdiikj";


        var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        }, scopes,
        Environment.UserName, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("MyAppsToken")).Result;
```

Please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code which initiates the authorize for with Google? Whats redirect uri you are sending right now? How do you send it?

Comment: string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                               DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,};

            var clientId = "ododoiodjkd";
            var clientSecret = "siojdokidpod" ;

            var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret
            }, scopes,
            Environment.UserName, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("MyAppsToken")).Result;

Comment: I am not able to set the redirect url which should be localhost:52444/CloudStorage/Drive

Comment: You should add your code in the original question. Code in comments is not readable.

Comment: What kind of application you are developing? Is it web application or windows application? Are you following [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet) tutorial from Google developers?  If you are developing asp.net MVC web application then you can follow [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth). There is a section related to MVC application in that page which explains how the MVC application should be developed

Comment: Hello, it is a dot net core web app. Right now, it is having redirect localhost:someport/authorize like a winapp It should instead have  AuthCallback/IndexAsync I am trying to find how can this be changed.

Comment: FYI On Google's it is a webapp and I tried to follow the MVC guide. Unfortunately, it is redirecting incorrectly still.

Comment: I fixed it using my own implementation of GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow. I have a custom redirect uri so it was needed anyhow. Thanks for the help!